# How to keep Tomcat working after GC overhead error?

Tags: tomcat, garbage-collection, restart, overhead

Many users of this commynity have experienced a GC Overhead error in Tomcat. The main problem as consequence of it is that Tomcat stops working (does not handle http request anymore) and there is no other way that restart the Tomcat server.

The question is:
- is it possible to keep Tomcat running after a GC Overhead event without restart it? Ok, the request generating the GC Overhead can be lost, but the further requests? They are no longer served until the restart of the server..

Or an alternative could be to restart automatically (or make the Tomcat process crash and close) after a GC Overhead event.

Is there a monitoring tool to check Tomcat responsiveness?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: Thank you but my question is a bit different than "what is a GC overhead error". I ask how keep Tomcat working after that the error above happens.

Comment: The answers in the linked question cover that.

Comment: "Increase memory size" is not an answer of my question.

Comment: There is more than one answer, hence the plural.